# What in this program

Tags: mysql, php

I have been complete my class that will connecting to mysql server.
When I running it I got an error:

> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: This is usually a temporary
>   error during hostname resolution and
>   means that the local server did not
>   receive a response from an
>   authoritative server. in
>   C:\wamp\www.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: [2002]
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: This is usually a (trying to
>   connect via tcp://test:3306) in
>   C:\wamp\www.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: This is usually a temporary
>   error during hostname resolution and
>   means that the local server did not
>   receive a response from an
>   authoritative server. in
>   C:\wamp\www.php on line 18 Error
>   cannnot connect to mysql server

I check my sql server that it had high privileges and dont have a password.

my code:

```
<?php
class mysql
{
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $host;

    function mysql($username, $password, $database, $host)
    {
        $this->user = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;
    }
    function connect()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)
                or die("Error cannnot connect to mysql server");
        echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server";
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
}
$connect = new mysql('127.0.0.1','root','','test');
$connect->connect();
?>
```

Comment: Order of your arguments in $connect = new mysql('127.0.0.1','root','','test'); is wrong, first argument should be username, not the host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to defined each property:

```
var $user;
var $password;
var $database;
var $host;
```

like these:

```
private $user;
private $password;
private $database;
private $host;
```

And create setter and getter methods for each property, an example:

```
public setUser($user){ 
   $this->user = $user; 
}

public getUser(){
   return $this->user;
}
```

Now, I'm sure you are asking yourself: Why? [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) there is the answer :-)

bye